# Generating Indicators in large data frames

Tags: r, memory, dataframe, plyr, reshape2

The objective is to create indicators for a factor/string variable in a data frame. That dataframe has > 2mm rows, and running R on windows, I don't have the option of using plyr with .parallel=T. So I'm taking the "divide and conquer" route with plyr and reshape2.

Running melt and cast runs out of memory, and using

```
ddply( idata.frame(items) , c("ID") , function(x){
       (    colSums( model.matrix( ~ x$element - 1) ) > 0   )
} , .progress="text" )
```

or

```
ddply( idata.frame(items) , c("ID") , function(x){
           (    elements %in% x$element   )
    } , .progress="text" )
```

does take a while. The fastest approach is the call to tapply below. Do you see a way to speed this up? The %in% statement runs faster than the model.matrix call. Thanks.

```
set.seed(123)

dd <- data.frame(
  id  = sample( 1:5, size=10 , replace=T ) ,
  prd = letters[sample( 1:5, size=10 , replace=T )]
  )

prds <- unique(dd$prd)

tapply( dd$prd , dd$id , function(x) prds %in% x )
```

Comment: I'm confused by your example.  You're splitting `dd$prd` by `dd$id`, then asking which values of `prds` are represented in each id -- but `prds` is not sorted (!) Did you want `prds <- sort(unique(dd$prd))` (that would make much more sense to me ...) ?

Comment: As long as the indicators (the logicals) corresponding to elements available in prds have the same order across IDs, it doesn't matter how they're sorted.

Comment: OK. See my other question, in my answer below ...

Comment: I wonder how [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) compares to `bigtable` in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this problem, the packages `bigmemory` and `bigtabulate` might be your friends. Here is a slightly more ambitious example:

```
library(bigmemory)
library(bigtabulate)

set.seed(123)

dd <- data.frame(
  id = sample( 1:15, size=2e6 , replace=T ), 
  prd = letters[sample( 1:15, size=2e6 , replace=T )]
  )

prds <- unique(dd$prd)

benchmark(
bigtable(dd,c(1,2))>0,
table(dd[,1],dd[,2])>0,
xtabs(~id+prd,data=dd)>0,
tapply( dd$prd , dd$id , function(x) prds %in% x )
)
```

And the results of benchmarking (I'm learning new things all the time):

```
                                            test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1                      bigtable(dd, c(1, 2)) > 0          100  54.401 1.000000    51.759    3.817          0         0
2                    table(dd[, 1], dd[, 2]) > 0          100 112.361 2.065422   107.526    6.614          0         0
4 tapply(dd$prd, dd$id, function(x) prds %in% x)          100 178.308 3.277660   166.544   13.275          0         0
3                xtabs(~id + prd, data = dd) > 0          100 229.435 4.217478   217.014   16.660          0         0
```

And that shows `bigtable` winning out by a considerable amount. The results are pretty much that all prds are in all IDs, but see `?bigtable` for details on the format of the results.

Comment: The run just completed (using bigtable) on the actual dataset (!).

Answer (score 2):

Can you say a little bit more how the problem would scale in terms of numbers of levels, numbers of IDs, etc.  (if you keep the numbers of levels fixed, then for enough individuals the indicator matrix you're computing will approach all TRUE/all 1 ...)?  I expected that `xtabs` would be faster, but it's not for an example of this size ...

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(
          tapply( dd$prd , dd$id , function(x) prds %in% x ),
          xtabs(~id+prd,data=dd)>0)

     test        replications elapsed relative 
1 tapply(...)             100   0.053 1.000000
2 xtabs(...) > 0          100   0.120 2.264151
```

Comment: There are 13.5million items (across 780,000 IDs, so multiple items per IDs). There are 83 different elements in prd. Thanks for drawing my attention to rbenchmark by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of the `%in%` function seems backwards to me. And if you want an true/false result for each row of data then you should use either %in% as a vector operation or  `ave`. Although it's not needed here you might want to use it if there were a more complex function that needed to be applied to every item.

```
set.seed(123)

dd <- data.frame(
  id  = sample( 1:5, size=10 , replace=T ) ,
  prd = letters[sample( 1:5, size=10 , replace=T )]
  )

prds <- unique(dd$prd)
target.prds <- prds[1:2]
dd$prd.in.trgt <- with( dd, prd %in% target.prds)
```

Comment: There will be as many indicators as there are `prds` ( or `target.prds`): `c(1,2,3) %in% c(1)` will indicate that 1 is in that record, but neither 2 nor 3.

Comment: You cannot just redefine %in% to be something that it is not. And a dataframe needs all elements to have regular number of entries per row. You need to use a data structure that accommodates a variable number if "hits", ... either a logical matrix of TRUEs and FALSEs or a list.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're saying. The call to `%in%` will always return the same number of logicals. I started out with `function(x) unique(x$prd)` in the `tapply` call, and that would have produced a ragged array.